# Expand a YouTube video on click, like Facebook

Tags: jquery, youtube

I have a site with a lot of thumbnails for YouTube videos that follow this format:

```
<iframe width="250" height="141" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<VIDEOID>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen ></iframe>
```

What I would like to happen is when you click to play the video the player goes to a size of 500x500 before it starts playing.  It would need to do this for any video in this set.

This is the same principal as what happens when someone clicks a video on Facebook, it goes to a larger size then starts playing.

Any help on doing this with jQuery or another method would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it facebook also using iframe?

Comment: use a plugin like jPlayer, or any number of other video or youtube plugins

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Facebook doesn't show an frame to begin with; they show an image with a "play" button on top of it:

[image: https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQD6a6UECdMO9RsC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fi4.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FsWwNTSj2Cy0%2Fmqdefault.jpg]

(scaled down) plus

[image: https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yG/r/Gj2ad6O09TZ.png]

equals

[image: https://dl-web.dropbox.com/u/113308/so/fb_movie.png]

When you click on this image, the image (and the surrounding markup) is replaced by the `iframe`.

Since the images load faster than a Flash player, this allows a speedy load of a page even with many such thumbnails on it.

[Edit] Here is a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/5BKYZ/4/).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize this but once I saw this I did it a similar way.  Thanks!